# Texting existing JMS application

Tags: spring, jms

I am working on existing project which uses JMS and spring. I am new to JMS. I need to test that application. My aim is to test that my classes which are used in the application are executed or not.
So can anybody provide me a way in which I can test the application which uses JMS?

I have searched on Google but everyone get started with a sample application. But I want to test my existing application, meaning how my application gets connected with another module. Is there any tool like SOAPUI for JMS test of my existing application, meaning something from which I can execute my classes or listener.

**Edit 1**

There is a scenario in my project that my module listen a JMS Queue and send SMS or Email to user but actually I am not getting that how my module connected to other module can anybody give me a way so I can find in that direction means which services or APIs used in there.

Comment: Are you talking about unit testing(just your classes) or end to end testing(application, not just your class)?

Comment: whatever is good. Unit testing is also work for me or if there is way to test the application then it is also fine for me.

Comment: Please someone can send me a solution on this, i have tried a lot but no success. I am trying to test onMessage() of listener, my requirement is to read already present messages from queue and send mail to user. I have written a sample java app which call my listener, but after getBean() from application context onMessage() not get invoke and if i try to call like listener.onMessage(..) then the question is how i can pass message argument to that method.